# Video youtube jerk Ubuntu groovy

Tags: video, youtube

on my Raspberry PI 4 with 4 GB Ram I have installed Buster and on another SD Card Ubuntu 20.10. If I watch a Video on youtube at Buster there is no problem compared with groovy the video is jerking. How can that be, Buster with 32 Bit and Ubuntu with 64 Bit. I was expecting that groovy is just as quick? Do I have configure something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the 64 bit drivers for hardware acceleration are not available yet.

Open Bug Report: https://github.com/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-OS-64bit/issues/52

Most likely Ubuntu will obtain the drivers once they are released in Raspberry Pi OS.

It was reported in the [Manjaro Forums](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-use-hardware-acceleration-in-raspberry-pi-with-manjaro/10235/13?u=archisman) that kernel 5.10 brings some improvements.

Comment: kralq commented on Jun 27: https://github.com/raspberrypi/Raspberry-Pi-OS-64bit/issues/52#issuecomment-650581748 - *The Unofficial 64-bit Ubuntu https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-4-ubuntu-server-desktop-18-04-3-image-unofficial/ is miles ahead of the official Ubuntu images with 3D video hardware acceleration.*

Comment: I hope I am right. actually on my Raspberry Buster runs on 5.4 kernel and groovy on 5.8